# How to group color codes into one single file in a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight App

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro

I've got an Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app, using the Caliburn.Micro framework.

Atm all my color codes are hardcoded into the place they get used.

```
Foreground="#c8d75a"
```

Which means i have that color code hardcoded about 150 places in my app.

So i thought i would group all colors into one file and then have a reference to the color in my xaml pages.

I've done a lot of Google searches and they all turn up with the answer "Use a Resource Directory" and then in my xaml page i would be able to use the variables in the Directory like i would with any other static resoruce

```
{StaticResource LightGreen}
```

My problem is i don't have any templates called Resource Directory. So my question is this:
Is this even possible in a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app to add a Resource Directory? if not what should i use then?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course it is possible. I don't know why you don't have a file template for a `ResourceDictionary` but you can create one yourself.

Lets say you have a folder named `Resources` in your main project, then you need to create a file with the `.xaml` extension, for example `Constants.xaml`. You can do this outside visual studio and then just copy the file to your project.

The contents of the file should be something like the following:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <!-- SOCIAL NETWORKS -->
    <Color x:Key="FacebookColor">#3B5998</Color>
    <Color x:Key="GoogleColor">#DB4A39</Color>
    <Color x:Key="TwitterColor">#00A0D1</Color>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FacebookBrush" Color="{StaticResource FacebookColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GoogleBrush" Color="{StaticResource GoogleColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TwitterBrush" Color="{StaticResource TwitterColor}"/>

    <!-- BOOLEANS -->
    <system:Boolean x:Key="BoolTrue">True</system:Boolean>
    <system:Boolean x:Key="BoolFalse">False</system:Boolean>

    <!-- COLORS -->
    <Color x:Key="LightGreen">#c8d75a</Color>

    <!-- BRUSHES -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightGreenBrush" Color="{StaticResource LightGreen}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then you need to include the created `ResourceDictionary` to your `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Constants.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

or if you want to include the dictionary in a page:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Constants.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: Yes thanks this worked, i just created a phone page and pasted your code into it. Thank you so much.